# Modelsim simulate clock divider

Tags: vhdl

I have made a code for a Clock divider with the benefit of transforming the 50mHz on the board to a 100 Hz with this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;


entity clock_divider is
  port (
    clk_50Mhz : in  std_logic;
    reset       : in  std_logic;
     clk_100Hz   : out std_logic
     );
end clock_divider;

architecture Behavioral of clock_divider is

  signal counter : unsigned(23 downto 0);
  --signal clk_2Hz_i : std_logic;
  signal clk_100Hz_i : std_logic;


begin

  gen_clk : process (clk_50Mhz, reset)
  begin 
    if reset = '1' then
      clk_100Hz_i   <= '0';
      counter   <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk_50Mhz) then   -- rising clock edge
      if counter = X"2625A0" then     -- 2500000 in hex
        counter   <= (others => '0');
        clk_100Hz_i   <= not clk_100Hz_i;
      else
        counter <= counter + "1";
      end if;
    end if;
  end process gen_clk;

clk_100Hz <= clk_100Hz_i;

end Behavioral;`
```

But have any a good solution to simulate this code in Modelsim to see if it works? I have tried, but i dont get any good solutions.

Comment: What did you try and what results did you get? What is your problem, exactly, with the simulation of this model?

Comment: Hi! I have tried to simulate the code above, but havent find a code simulatione code. I there a simple simulation code that could show if the clock is converted to a 100Hz clock?

Comment: How long did you run the simulation?

Answer (score 1):

For simulating long delays it is often useful to have a means to speed up the simulation to get faster results. This can be done with a top level Boolean generic that you check to decide between the real delay constant and a smaller one for simulation.

Simulating a 100Hz clock isn't especially challenging though. There will only be 1e6 clock events for a single 100Hz period. You can further automate the validation by having a process check that the delay between successive edges on the output is ~5ms within some margin of error.

```vhdl
constant CLOCK_FREQ   : integer := 50e6; -- 50 MHz
constant TARGET_FREQ  : integer := 100;  -- 100 Hz
...
constant MAX_ERROR            : delay_length := 10 ns;
constant EXPECTED_HALF_PERIOD : delay_length := 1 sec / TARGET_FREQ / 2;
assert abs(clk_100Hz'last_event - EXPECTED_HALF_PERIOD) <= MAX_ERROR
  report "100Hz clock has wrong period"
  severity error;
```

Then you don't have to bother measuring edges in the waveform window. Note that this assert needs to be inhibited on the first generated 100Hz edge to avoid a false error at the start of the simulation.

In general it is best to avoid having magic numbers in your code if at all possible. An explanatory comment, while helpful, can get out of sync with the actual code. There is no need to manually convert the count to hex. Just use a counter of an `integer` type constrained from 0 to 250000-1 (not 2500000) and let simulation/synthesis sort out the implementation details.

In this case you have an obscure bug because you've calculated the wrong constant value. You only need an 18-bit counter so your manually constructed implementation using `unsigned` also wastes bits. And finally, down-counting to zero is preferable for simple counters since comparison with 0 is cheaper in some target architectures (One big NOR gate).

```vhdl
constant DELAY_CYCLES : integer := CLOCK_FREQ / TARGET_FREQ / 2 - 1;
signal counter : integer range 0 to DELAY_CYCLES;

if reset = '1' then
  counter <= DELAY_CYCLES;
elsif rising_edge(clk_50Mhz) then
  if counter = 0 then
    counter <= DELAY_CYCLES;
  else
    counter <= counter - 1;
  end if;
end if;
```

Now if you need to change the system to generate 80 Hz or 120 Hz all that is required is a simple, obvious constant change to `TARGET_FREQ` without needing to know how to recompute an opaque hex value. Everything else will automatically adjust without further effort.